# AWS Target Group Unhealthy - Docker Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ssl, docker-container, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm new to AWS and am having some issues setting up my Docker Container .net API. The Docker container is built to allows 80 & 443.

I was able to access the container via the elastic IP before I added in the other features, but only through Http not Https. So then I added in the Route 53 Hosted Zone, Load balancer with Target Group, and a SSL Certificate.

Now I cannot access either through **http** or **https**, and my target group is saying it's health check is unhealthy.

Is there a different way of setting up the target to do the health checks with a Docker container, or have I just made an error along the way?

### Route 53

I am using Route 53 with a hosted zone, with a record set to:

Record Type: **A**

Routing Policy: **Simple Routing**

Route Traffic To: **Alias to Application and Classic Load Balancer**

### Load Balancer

My load balancer is type **Application**, and I have 2 listeners:

#### Listener 1

ID: **Http: 80**

Security Policy: **N/A**

SSL Certificate: **N/A**

Default: **redirecting to HTTPS://#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query}**

#### Listener 2

ID: **Https: 443**

Security Policy: **ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08**

SSL Certificate: **Default**

Default: **Forwarding to target**

### Target

Then I have a target to my instance.

Port: **443**

Zone: **eu-west-2c**

Health Status: **Unhealthy**

Health Status Details: **Health Checks Failed**

##### Health Checks

Protocol: **HTTPS**

Path: **/**

Port: **Traffic Port**

Healthy Threshold: **5 Consecutive Health Check Success**

Unhealthy Threshold: **2 Consecutive Health Check Failures**

Timeout: **5 Seconds**

Interval: **30 Seconds**

Success Codes: **200**

I also have an elastic IP, and my instance is running a Docker Container.

Thanks in advance for any assitance.

Comment: Why would your target be 443? Do you have valid SSL certificates setup on the instances?

Comment: I have a valid SSL Certificate for the Domain name on Route 53, and then this is applied to the Load Balancer route for HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

Your target can't be `Port: 443` unless your application fully supports HTTPS and has proper SSL certificates. If you have only SSL for the domain and ALB, your target probably is not 443. You have to double check what port is your application listening on the instances and what protocol it uses (should be http, not https).

Comment: Thankyou for your help, it certainly pointed me in the right direction.